# StanfordCoreNLP : TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 14. Encountered: "E" (69), after : "\\"

Tags: stanford-nlp

The complete stacktrace is as follows. Any idea whats wrong?

Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 14.  Encountered: "E" (69), after : "\"
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParserTokenManager.getNextToken(TokenSequenceParserTokenManager.java:1029)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.jj_ntk(TokenSequenceParser.java:3353)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.CoreMapNode(TokenSequenceParser.java:1386)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.NodeBasic(TokenSequenceParser.java:1360)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.NodeGroup(TokenSequenceParser.java:1327)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.NodeDisjConj(TokenSequenceParser.java:1266)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.BracketedNode(TokenSequenceParser.java:1127)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.SeqRegexBasic(TokenSequenceParser.java:833)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.SeqRegexDisjConj(TokenSequenceParser.java:1020)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.SeqRegex(TokenSequenceParser.java:790)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.SeqRegexWithAction(TokenSequenceParser.java:1643)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.parseSequenceWithAction(TokenSequenceParser.java:37)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern.compile(TokenSequencePattern.java:186)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.ScorePhrases.runParallelApplyPats(ScorePhrases.java:215)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.ScorePhrases.applyPats(ScorePhrases.java:326)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.ScorePhrases.learnNewPhrasesPrivate(ScorePhrases.java:397)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.ScorePhrases.learnNewPhrases(ScorePhrases.java:177)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply4Label(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:1716)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:1591)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.surface.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.main(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:2485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also replied on the github page: We are releasing the new version of the software in a few days. This bug is most probably fixed in that -- I used the files you provided in the github page with the new code and it works. Stay tuned!

Comment: I am using the 3.5.1 version of Stanford CoreNLP and am using TokensRegex to extract patterns like JASON-1234, SBP-3254 etc from my data and have encountered `Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 22.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/)-(\\d+)"` The culprit line is `TokenSequencePattern p1 = TokenSequencePattern
      .compile("(JSON|JPA|SBP/)-(\\d+)");` I have tried so many permutations and combinations of Regex but can't get this to work. Your help would be greatly appreciated.